# how do I allow users to create a playlist from a song library in SQL and python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am making a little program using sqlite with python and I am not sure how to allow a user to create a playlist from a song library. Also I need the user to Ibe able to save the playlist (no actual songs are included). i have a database with 3 tables(users, library and playlist table).

```
import sqlite3
import os
from shutil import copyfile

db = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
#prints a welcome message
print("WELCOME TO BlaBlah !!!")
print("We have three genre types avalible.\nPop\nHip Hop\nClassic\nWe also have five avalible artists.\nDean\nIsbean\nNoazy\nKepen\nDrip\n")
answer = input("Do you already have an account ?\nIf yes type 'y' if no type 'n'! ")#gets user input
loggedIn = False #sets boolean to false
if answer == "y": #uses the user input to see which step needs to be taken next
    cursor = db.cursor()
    username = input("Enter Your username ") #asks for user to input username
    password = input("Enter Your password ") #asks for user to input password
    cursor.execute('''SELECT username, password, address, birth, artist, genre FROM users''')
    for row in cursor: #makes a for loop that goes through the file until all rows are checked
        if row[0]==username: #checks if row[0] is equal to username
            if row[1]==password: #checks if row[1] is equal to password
                print("you are logged in") #if both rows match then it prints out a message
                loggedIn == True #sets boolean to true
                change = input("Your fav artist is "+row[4]+" and your fav genre is "+row[5]+".\nTo change something press '1' otherwise press any key ")
                playlist = input("To create a new playlist press '2' or to view a created playlist press '1' ")
                if change == "1":
                    newChange = input("To change fav artist type '1' To change fav genre type '2' ")
                    if newChange =="1":
                        newArtist = input("Enter new fav artist ")
                        cursor.execute('''UPDATE students SET artist = ? WHERE username = ?''',(newArtist ,username))
                        db.commit()
                    else:
                        newGenre = input("Enter new fav genre ")
                        cursor.execute('''UPDATE students SET genre = ? WHERE username = ?''',(newGenre ,username))
                        db.commit()
                elif playlist == '1':
                    print('View Created playlist')
                elif playlist == '2':
                    runit = input('To view a song library press "1" ')
                    if runit == '1':

                        #cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS library(song_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, song TEXT, artist TEXT, genre TEXT, time INTEGER)''') 

                        cursor.execute('''SELECT song_id, song, artist, genre, time FROM library ORDER BY song ASC''')
                        for row in cursor:
                            song_id = row[0]
                            songName = row[1]
                            name = row[2]
                            age = row[3]
                            time = row[4]
                            print('--------Song record---------')
                            print('Song_id: ' +str(song_id))
                            print('Song Name: ' + str(songName))
                            print('Artist Name: ' + name)
                            print('Genre: ' + str(age))
                            print('Time: ' + str(time))
                            print('-------------------------------\n')

                        createPlaylist = input('to create a playlist press "1" ')
                        if createPlaylist == '1':
                            cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists(user_id INTEGER, playlist_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, song_id)''')
                        else:
                            print('####')
                else:
                    print('####')
```

How do I allow the playlist to be created saved and viewed?

Comment: You should create all tables **prior** to any user input... Then you would insert values into the table in response to entered values

Comment: but how do i actually create a working playlist table where users can input their favorite songs and create multiple playlists ?

Comment: I suggest you start with how you get the `user_id` value. For example, how are you going to detect what information is associated with a previous user, vs creating a new one...?  That task itself has nothing to do with songs and playlists, and should be a question on its own. As it stands, your question is too broad.

Comment: I already have the user_id in the user table

Comment: Okay, great, but my question was how are you using that ID to associate it with the person entering the information?

Comment: It is all in an if statement so if a user is logged in it will display their data etc

Comment: That's not very clear from the question... Can you please show a [mcve] of all code you currently have?

Comment: How do i send you the whole code ?

Comment: You don't send it to me, you [edit] your question to include more of it

Comment: ahhh i understand